# CoreBluetooth on Mac Command line application

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to build a Command Line app that uses CoreBluetooth. Problem is, it doesn't work on command line apps.

I've moved the my `CoreBluetooth` code (a class that implements the CBCentralManagerDelegate protocol - let's call this class `myBLEManager`) from the Command Line app project to another Mac OS GUI App.

I ran some tests in `ViewDidLoad()` -- supersample, I just init a `myBLEManager` that creates an instance of `CBCentralManager` on initialization, then calls `scanForPeripherals`.

This is what I do in both the CLI and GUI projects. Difference is `centralManagerDidUpdateState` never gets called in the CLI project. but it does in the GUI Mac app.

Comment: Does your command-line tool have a run loop?

Comment: @duskwuff, I do not. Thanks for the hint, I'll look into it

Comment: Do you want to post an answer ? Or should I when done ? up to you

Comment: Posted an answer. :)

Comment: @kmn could you update the answer to show a more detailed example of your main class and your myBLEManager class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Callbacks in most Apple frameworks are delivered through your application's main run loop. If your command-line tool does not have a run loop, it cannot receive callbacks that are sent this way.

Without a runloop, the only way for the framework to invoke your callback would be to run it on another thread, which could lead to weird behavior in an application that didn't expect that.

It's sufficient to add:

```
let runLoop = RunLoop.current
let distantFuture = Date.distantFuture
while running == true && runLoop.run(mode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode, before: distantFuture) {

}
```

Comment: could you update the answer to show a more detailed example of your main class and your myBLEManager class?

Comment: @angryip I didn't write the program.

Comment: fair enough, i'll reach out to the author

Comment: Here's an example I found that uses RunLoop to access CoreLocation from a command line application: https://gist.github.com/cmittendorf/2c6eefc6dd128b323428

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5+ this is the syntax for a Runloop:

```
import Foundation

let runLoop = RunLoop.current
let distantFuture = Date.distantFuture
var shouldKeepRunning = true

while shouldKeepRunning == true && runLoop.run(mode: RunLoop.Mode.default, before: distantFuture) {
    
}
```